# Fabric -- use common tasks from parent module

Tags: python, fabric

Using the @task and submodule convention, my "parent" fabfile imports two submodules ("dev" and "stable" whose tasks are defined in their respective **init**.py files).  How to I get a @task in the dev module to invoke a task defined in the parent fabfile.  I can't seem to get the imports to work correctly.

I also tried using the imp.load_source but that produced a nasty circular import (fabfile.py imports dev which tries to import ../fabfile.py).

Using this as an example: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/tasks.html#going-deeper

How would a task defined in lb.py call something in the top **init**.py or a task in migrations.py call something in the top **init**.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke fabric task by name:

```
from fabric.api import execute, task
@task
def innertask():
    execute("mytask", arg1, key1=kwarg1)
```